# Max Ram Memory on Google Colab Pro

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to run some image processing algorithms on google colab but ran out of memory (after the free 25Gb option).

I am thinking of purchasing Colab Pro, but the website is not that informative (it says double, but, is it double 12 or double 25?).

The images that I am working on are whole scan images (15000px x 15000px approx or more). Any other suggestions on how to tackle this problem? (on my current system 32Gb Ram I solved this through swap memory)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the upper toolbar > select 'Runtime' > 'Change Runtime Type' > hardware accelerator: select 'TPU'. This will provide you with 35.5GB instead of 25GB of free RAM

Comment: This works for me, but I find 35gb still not enough. Is there any way to go beyond that, even a paid solution?

Comment: Does that mean i also need to change my code to support TPU?

Answer (score 2):

You can now subscribe to the [Colab Pro Plus](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) solution provided by Google, which has a maximum RAM of 52Gb.